# Removing years old grout from drywall in kitchen

Tags: drywall, kitchens, grout, patching-drywall

I'm about to get new cabinets and countertops for my kitchen. I've removed the old cabinets and countertops, but unfortunately the previous owners had a nasty tile countertop and it looks like grout made its way to the wall. My question is, do I just cut the drywall out and replace the section, or is there a smarter way to remove this grout? Note: when the new countertops are put in, this grout would be visible.[image: grout on wall][image: grout and torn paper]

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd just scrape it off with a putty knife.  If there are any dig and deep gouges after that step repair with spackle.  Then give it a skim coat of drywall compound, sand, and repaint.

Basically what you suggested except not actually new drywall, the steps are the same tho.

Answer (score 0):

The important step in all of it is the blending work, which is the finishing art we all have to hate to love. In fact, NEW drywall you'd now be blending seams, so +1 this since its less work.

Comment: Giving this a shot. Having a really hard time getting the grout off though using the putty knife. I assume I have to get most all of it off or the drywall compound won't stick well right?